# QMessageBox cerrar automaticamente

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Favor si alguien me puede ayudar diciendo como puedo hacer para generar un `QMessageBox` que se cierre automáticamente después de x segundos sin presionar ningún botón.
dejo un ejemplo del código que tengo

```
QMessageBox Logo;
Logo.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/icons/Logo.jpg").scaled(QSize(185,215),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
Logo.setStandardButtons(0);
    Logo.show();
    //sleep(3); /*al ejecutar esto solo genera que se demore en aparecer la imagen */
Gui::MainWindow win;
    //Logo.close();/*no me esta cerrando el QMessageBox*/
    win.show();
    return app.exec();
```

Pd: todo esta ejecutado en el main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo solucione dejo solución si a alguien le interesa, espero que les sirva

```
Gui::MainWindow win;
QMessageBox Logo;
    Logo.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/icons/Logo.jpg").scaled(QSize(185,215),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    Logo.setStandardButtons(0);
    Logo.show();
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer ,  SIGNAL(timeout ()),&Logo,SLOT(accept()));
    QObject::connect(&timer ,  SIGNAL(timeout ()),&win,SLOT(show()));
    timer.start(3000);//esto es solo por si alguien quiere que se espere 3 segundos antes de iniciar el win.show()

    return app.exec();
```